# div border radius problem (on firefox and opera)

Tags: cross-browser, css

as you see there are two pictures.First, on chrome . There are Beğen and Yorumlar buttons on right side.Border is looking very well..

But second pictures shows that ; firefox and opera have problem with border radius.I try to do border-witdh:thin, border:1px solid etc.. But Its look like same.

How can handdle it ? Do you have any idea ?

sorry for my english.Thank you

[image on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDiza.png)

[image on ff and opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69KcH.png)

Comment: any chance of providing a working demon on jsfiddle.com? it'll help us work out what's happening if we can see it for real rather than just in a graphic.

Comment: I'cant explain my problem.Sorry.AS you see blue buttons' broder very well.I'dont use border.Border:0 .

I mean firefox and opera smearing border.They show like there is border.Actually there is no border.I dont want to shadow, I dont want to border.

I have background image . I want to show sharply.

Look at the photo.Firefox show the border.Chrome is very well.In really time , div has no border !

[photo](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ZGVCFkKiSQk/TpXUKpYll6I/AAAAAAAAAKI/SbLRzAsZCu0/s782/btn2.png)

Comment: I fixed :) PRoblem is I used background color and background image same time.Now I'm using just background image . there is no problem.

Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This effect is commonly referred to as "background bleed", or "leaking". It can be fixed through some simple CSS:

```
-moz-background-clip: padding;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
```

I first learned of this from Mike Harding's blog:
http://tumble.sneak.co.nz/post/928998513/fixing-the-background-bleed

And here's the W3C spec:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-clip

Answer (score 1):

... it almost looks like may get away without using border at all. There's enough contrast between the button and the background. Did you try using outer glow of 1px (blur-radius)?

```
-moz-box-shadow: [position-x] [position-y] [blur-radius] [color];
-webkit-box-shadow: [position-x] [position-y] [blur-radius] [color];
box-shadow: [position-x] [position-y] [blur-radius] [color];
```

Answer (score 0):

To help with chome's border to `border:1px double ...`. I know chrome has an issue with borders with a radius. Setting it to double rather than solid helps clean it up a bit. Kind of annoying.