# Firefox scaling issues causes pixelated / blurry borders

Tags: html, css, firefox, mobile

[github repo with shortest code replicating problem](https://github.com/blaine-moodley/firefox_border_issues.git)

Basically i have a webpage that i have scaled down using the "viewport" meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.25">
```

The issue is that Firefox renders ALL my curved borders really blurry.

If an element has the following CSS applied while being viewed from a Bugzilla mobile browser, the resulting borders are really blurry/pixelated.

```css
.element {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

@media screen {
  .element {
    font-size: 4vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.25">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="element">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Screenshot of webpage in Chrome (devtools Mobile browser):

[image]

Screenshot of webpage in Firefox (devtools Mobile browser):

[image]

From what i've found online it seems Firefox has a long history of scaling based rendering bugs but this is the first time ive seen issues with curved borders.

Comment: i have realised the above snippet doesnt replicate the problem when viewed from a firefox mobile browser.  Here is the link to the repo. https://github.com/blaine-moodley/firefox_border_issues.git . this replicates the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what  that is related to background bleed and you may probably find its reason in this discussion https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=921341

To answer your question which has already been asked in this thread [div border radius problem (on firefox and opera)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740423/div-border-radius-problem-on-firefox-and-opera)
I recommend you using these properties in your css regarding with the mentioned answer

-moz-background-clip

-webkit-background-clip

background-clip

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, it appears background-bleed isnt the issue but maybe the anti-aliasing done by Firefox?

Comment: I had a form of this problem (possibly not exactly the same as the OP), which manifested only on external monitors on macOS. This answer did help me fix my problem. Specifically I had to set background-clip: padding-box;